# Rails 3.1 Asset pipeline + SASS + inline SASS in HAML (filter)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, haml, sass

Although inline sass / inline stylesheets are not recommended. I just had a case where I can't get around it, so in case you want to do something like

index.html.haml:

```
:sass
  @import my_styles
```

app/assets/stylesheets/my_styles.css.sass:

```
body
  background-color: black
```

i.e. use your stylesheets lying in app/assets/stylesheets as inline styles, just add an initializer to your rails app with

```
::Sass::Plugin.options[:load_paths] = Rails.application.config.sass[:load_paths].to_a
```

Don't know if this is use to anybody, but I thought it's worth sharing.

Comment: is inline stuff added to the app.css?

Comment: Please 1) edit your question to *make it a question* then 2) add an answer with the solution.  Seems odd, but that's how we do it here.  Once you have edited your question, please flag and ask it to be reopened so that you can add the answer.  Thanks.